# PySide TableView and Variant data - Display Role Not Displaying

Tags: pyside, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel, qvariant

I have this code, which when i run it in PyQt it works totally fine, but when i run it in pyside things get wierd. I get all the columns and rows im supposed to, and if i go to them via scripting and get the data, each cell says what it should. However, even though i set these as display roles, NO text shows in the table.
None in the headers, none in any of the cells. Im at a loss!

(For thos wondering, NulLVariant() just returns either None or QVariant() depending if were on pyside or pyqt)

This model is meant to take a List of Dicts to addRows, and uses dict keys to make columns.

```
class CustomTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, parentTable=None):
        """
        Custom data model for holding table data.

        :param parent: The parent widget/layout so that this data model gets deleted properly on close.
        :param parentTable: the table that is using this data. This is used to get the font metrics of the table
        display font.
        """
        super(CustomTableModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.parent_table = parentTable
        self.auto_resize = False
        self._avg_font_w = 5
        self._resize_data = defaultdict(int)

        self.items = []
        self.headers = []

    def setParentTable(self, widget):
        """
        Sets the parent table widget so that we can get its font metrics for setting our column width with autoResize.
        :param widget: TableViewWidget
        :raise TypeError:
        """
        if not isinstance(widget, QtGui.QTableView):
            raise TypeError('Must be a TableView item')

        self.parent_table = widget

    def setAutoResize(self, b):
        """
        Turns on or off auto resize for the table. This gathers the font metrics of the parent table, and then loops
        over any current data, or newly added data (including table headers) to get the widest item, and sets the
        column width to fit this.
        :param b: bool
        :raise AttributeError:
        """
        if not self.parent_table:
            raise AttributeError('You must call setParentTable first to set the parent TableView item')

        self.auto_resize = b
        if b:
            self._autoAllResizeData()
            self._doColumnResize()
        else:
            self._resize_data = dict()

    def updateSize(self):
        """
        Force the table size to update to the current size data.
        """
        self._doColumnResize()

    def updateSizeData(self):
        """
        Force an update/regathering of all the size data for each row and column.
        """
        self._autoAllResizeData(True)
        self._doColumnResize()

    def _doColumnResize(self):
        for i in range(len(self.headers)):
            txt = self.headers[i]
            self.parent_table.setColumnWidth(i, self._resize_data.get(txt))

    def _getKeyList(self):
        if self.headers:
            return self.headers
        elif self.items:
            return sorted(self.items[0].keys())

    def _getTableFontWidth(self):
        self._avg_font_w = self.parent_table.fontMetrics().averageCharWidth()

    def _autoAllResizeData(self, reset=False):
        if not self._resize_data or reset is True:
            self._resize_data = defaultdict(int)

            key_list = self._getKeyList()
            for header in key_list:
                header_width = len(header) * (self._avg_font_w * 1.55)
                if header_width > self._resize_data[header]:
                    self._resize_data[header] = header_width

                for item in self.items:
                    value = item.get(header)
                    width = len(str(value)) * self._avg_font_w
                    if width > self._resize_data[header]:
                        self._resize_data[header] = width

    def _autoSingleResizeData(self, data):
        key_list = self._getKeyList()
        for header in key_list:
            value = data.get(header)
            if value:
                width = len(str(value)) * self._avg_font_w
                if width > self._resize_data[header]:
                    self._resize_data[header] = width

    def setHeaders(self, items):
        """
        This allows you to set your header item text
        :param items: a list of header text, ie ['Name', 'Email', 'Department']
        """
        lastCount = self.columnCount(QtCore.QModelIndex())
        self.headers = items

        self.beginRemoveColumns(QtCore.QModelIndex(), 0, lastCount)
        for x in range(lastCount):
            self.removeColumn(x)
        self.endRemoveColumns()

        self.beginInsertColumns(QtCore.QModelIndex(), 0, len(items)-1)
        self.endInsertColumns()

    def addRow(self, data):
        """
        Accepts a dict of data to add to the data model.
        :param data: dict (this should match the same key length/names as the other data in the table.)
        """
        row = len(self.items)
        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row)
        self.items.append(data)
        self.endInsertRows()

        if self.auto_resize:
            self._autoSingleResizeData(data)
            self._doColumnResize()

    def addRows(self, data):
        """
        Accepts a list of dicts to add them all to the table, with each list index being a row, and each dict key
        a column.
        :param data: list of dicts
        :raise ValueError:
        """
        if not isinstance(data, list) or not isinstance(data[0], dict):
            raise ValueError('input must be a list of dicts!')

        start_row = len(self.items)
        end_row = len(data) + start_row - 1

        self.beginInsertRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), start_row, end_row)
        self.items.extend(data)
        self.endInsertRows()

        if self.auto_resize:
            for item in data:
                self._autoSingleResizeData(item)
                self._doColumnResize()

    def removeRow(self, row):
        """
        Remove the row at index 'row'.
        :param row: int
        """
        self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), row, row)
        self.items.pop(row)
        self.endRemoveRows()

    def clear(self):
        """
        Clear all table data and start fresh.
        """
        rows = self.rowCount(QtCore.QModelIndex())
        self.beginRemoveRows(QtCore.QModelIndex(), 0, rows)
        self.items = []
        self.endRemoveRows()

        cols = self.columnCount(QtCore.QModelIndex())
        self.beginRemoveColumns(QtCore.QModelIndex(), 0, cols)
        self.headers = []
        self.endRemoveColumns()

    def rowCount(self, QModelIndex):
        """
        Return the row count.
        :param QModelIndex:
        :return:
        """
        return len(self.items)

    def columnCount(self, QModelIndex):
        """
        Return the column count (default 1)
        :param QModelIndex:
        :return:
        """
        try:
            return len(self.items[0].keys())
        except:
            return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        """
        Accepts a QModelIndex and a Qt.Role and returns the data at the given modelIndex.
        :param index: QModelIndex
        :param role: QtCore.Qt.<Role>
        :return:
        """
        row = index.row()
        col = index.column()
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            key_list = self._getKeyList()
            return QtCore.QVariant(str(self.items[row][key_list[col]]))

        return NullVariant()

    def intGetData(self, row, col):
        """
        Gets the data at 'row' and 'col'.
        :param row: int
        :param col: int
        :return: QVariant() data.
        """
        try:
            key_list = self._getKeyList()
            return QtCore.QVariant(str(self.items[row][key_list[col]]))
        except:
            return NullVariant()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        """
        Sets the header data based on our header key list.

        :param section: section header
        :param orientation: orientation
        :param role: Qt<Role>
        :return:
        """
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                if not self.items:
                    if section == 0:
                        return QtCore.QVariant(str("Column 1"))

                else:
                    key_list = self._getKeyList()
                    try:
                        return QtCore.QVariant(str(key_list[section]))
                    except:
                        return QtCore.QVariant('No Data')

        return NullVariant()


class CustomSortModel(QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """
        Custom QSortFilterProxyModel to allow sorting and filtering of our custom data model.
        :param parent: parent so that this model is deleted properly upon close.
        """
        super(CustomSortModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.countAllColumns = False
        self._sortingColumn = 0

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        """
        Overriding how we choose what rows match our input filter text.

        :param sourceRow: row index in question
        :param sourceParent: QModelIndex
        :return: bool (accepted or not)
        """
        txt = ''

        if self.countAllColumns:
            for x in range(len(self.sourceModel().headers)):
                txt += self.sourceModel().intGetData(sourceRow, x).toString()

        else:
            txt = self.sourceModel().intGetData(sourceRow, self._sortingColumn).toString()

        if self.filterRegExp().pattern():
            b = bool(re.search(str(self.filterRegExp().pattern()), str(txt)))
        else:
            b = bool(re.search('.*', str(txt)))

        return b

    def setFilterKeyColumn(self, col):
        """
        Sets which column index you want the filter to apply to. -1 or less means we search all columns - otherwise,
        the filter rules apply to the column index given.
        :param col: signed int
        :return:
        """
        if col <= -1:
            self.countAllColumns = True
            return

        self.countAllColumns = False
        self._sortingColumn = col
        super(CustomSortModel, self).setFilterKeyColumn(col)
```

Edit:
I was getting a wierd error when i tried to delete this question, but I have added a newer one, with a better cut down example for testing here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074825/pyside-qtableview-not-displaying-text-like-pyqt-does

Comment: i am very stuck here - cant for the life of me see whats happening!

Comment: Do not post a new question, edit this one instead.

Comment: I kept getting problems when i added a lot of text when i hit save on the edit - and redirect errors on delete, thats why i just added a little line - i normally do just edit. anyways, solved and merged now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your code in PySide gives a bunch of errors :

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QVariant'

That's because there is [no QVariant in PySide any more](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/pysideapi2.html#qvariant). Replacing all `QVariant`by regular python types fixes the code.

For example

```
return QtCore.QVariant('No Data')
```

becomes

```
return "No Data"
```

Comment: I just made this change this morning as a test and it worked and came here to answer my own haha. Thanks. The wierd thing is... i dont get errors for having a qvariant - it seems my pside HAS them, it just wont work with them. SO odd.